# Using the Create2 Tethered Driving program- inputting a string of keyboard presses

Tags: irobot-create, path-planning

I'm attempting to do a quick and dirty autonomous path with the create2. I'm using the tethered driving program seen [here](https://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Python_Tethered_Driving.pdf).

I set my own buttons just to make it rotate 90° and go forward one "pulse". I'd like to know, does anyone have any ideas on how to trick the attached Create2_TetheredDrive.py into thinking it's seeing a series of keyboard entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting your series of commands (or keyboard entries) as an array. After which, you can assign a *for* loop for this button, which will then run through the array of instructions.

The array might look something like this:

```
cmds = ['self.callbackKeyRight', 'self.callbackKeyDown',  'self.callbackKeyDown']
```

and the *for loop* code to run the array might look something like this:

```
 if event.type == '2': # KeyPress; need to figure out how to get constant
        if k == 'Z':   # Set some key here
            for i in range(len(cmds)):
                cmds[i] = True
                motionChange = True
                print 'Cmd number: ' + i
```

Comment: I implemented that code as you wrote it. I get the following error: 

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1535, in _call_
return self.func(*args)
File "Home/pi/Desktop/FILE", line 240, in callback Key
cmds[i]=True
NameError: Global name 'cmds1" not defined

Is there a particular place I should put the array to define it as global? Right now I put it under "def callbackKey...global cmds1"

Comment: However, if I just declare cdms1 within the command (under "elif k=='1':), and comment out the line "cmds1[i]=True", the shell displays the array, but doesn't actually carry out the command (convert it to the ASCII characters for the create). Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can try writing a function with args that calls the callbackkey through the array instead of calling the keys directly from the array.